# How to open Xcode from Terminal?

Tags: macos, xcode

```
kmorrison@Karls-MacBook-Pro ~ $ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
kmorrison@Karls-MacBook-Pro ~ $ xcode
-bash: xcode: command not found
```

How do I open Xcode?

Comment: Install Xcode and try `open -a xcode` or `open -b com.apple.dt.Xcode`... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Xcode is an app in /Applications — there's no CLI tool called `xcode`.

- For the GUI application, launch it from the Applications folder or with `open -a Xcode`.
- For the CLI build tool, it's called `xcodebuild`.

Answer (score 3):

If you've installed the Xcode IDE (for instance, via the App Store), you can open it from the terminal with `xed`.

From the man page (`man xed`):

> The `xed` tool launches the Xcode application and opens the given documents, or opens a new untitled document, optionally with the contents of standard in.

This option seems better than `open -a Xcode ...` since it has options, like `-l` to open at line number.

Comment: Open -a Xcode can also take parameters

Answer (score -2):

Have you even downloaded [Xcode IDE](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ide/)? The install should give you an option to open it.

If you already have it installed, try `CMD+SPACE` and search for `"Xcode"`.

All you have installed is a command line tools package that is separate from the actual IDE.